# exception in C++ with weird number printed

Tags: c++, exception

I have the following piece of code in my program:

```
//Get key given pionter
int SLL::Get(node* pt){
    try{
        if(pt!=NULL){
            node* temp = pt;
            return temp->key;
        }
        else {
            throw "Access the NULL pointer!!";
        }
    }
    catch(const char *s){
        cout << s << endl;
        cout << "Invalid input!" << endl;
    }
}
```

When I tested the exception case (Codeblocks), it gave me the following output

```
Access the NULL pointer!!
Invalid input!
4704284
```

I don't understand where I got this number? And the interesting thing is that no matter how many times I ran this test, the number is the same, which means it might not be some random address. And if I tested the non-exception cases, those 3 lines disappeared together.

So, I don't know what really happened. Hope someone can help me explain this. Thanks!

Comment: This is crying out for an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: The code that output that number is code that ran after the `catch` above completed. You haven't shown us that code.

Comment: I'll bet you wouldn't see "4704284" if you stepped through the two "cout's" in your "catch()" block ... and didn't step *outside* of your "catch()" block :)

Comment: @JoeZ , sorry, just started learning exception. So, you mean, I still need to return 0 or just return; then I don't understand why we need exception, because can't we just write a if statement and do the same thing? I don't really see the advantage of exception class now. Confused

Comment: @Cancan, Well, you normally don't throw an exception, catch it, and handle it all in the same function.

Comment: @Cancan - whenever, where ever you "catch" an exception ... *YOU'RE SUPPOSED TO FULLY HANDLE THE ERROR CONDITION* ... and return the program to a "known good state".  Instead, your "Get()" method *FAILS TO RETURN ANY VALID DATA*.  It returns garbage.  And it sounds like your calling code is simply printing that garbage.  You should have received a compiler warning (function doesn't return any value).  Didn't you?  SUGGESTION: add another line at the bottom: `return 222;`.  I'm guessing your program will now print "222".  I'm also guessing you should *LEARN TO USE YOUR DEBUGGER*.  IMHO..

Comment: @Cancan Why are you catching the exception?

Comment: @paulsm4 unfortunately, I think Codeblocks is not smart enough to report this warning or perhaps I didn't set high warning level.

Answer (score 1):

This function is supposed to return an `int`, but your exception-handling path has no `return` statement.  Likely it's the code that calls this that prints the "garbage" value.

I imagine something is calling this function like so:

```
key = whatever->Get();
cout << key << endl;
```

and that code is printing out the magic number above, returned by `SLL::Get()`.

One way to "fix" this would be to add `return -1;` at the end of `SLL::Get()`, since you'll only reach there if you don't return a proper key.